# How to pass std::vector<std::string> as char**?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, vector, argument-passing

I am trying to make a copy of `char *argv[]` so that i can pass them to a function that takes `char**`. First i have to remove some flags from the original `argv`:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    ::MessageBox(0,"Stopped at the entry point",0,0);
    std::string inChannelParam = "--ipc-in-channel";
    std::string outChannelParam = "--ipc-out-channel";

    std::string inChannelName;
    std::string outChannelName;

    std::vector<std::string> argv_copy;
    for(int i=0; i<argc; ++i)  {
        if(inChannelParam == argv[i]) {
            if(++i < argc) {
                inChannelName = argv[i];
                continue;
            }
        } else if(outChannelParam == argv[i]) {
            if(++i < argc) {
                outChannelName = argv[i];
                continue;
            }
        }
        argv_copy.push_back(argv[i]);
    }

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<char[]> > argv_copy_char;
    for(int i=0;i<argv_copy.size();++i) {
        argv_copy_char.push_back(std::unique_ptr<char[]>(new char[argv_copy[i].size()+1]));
        memcpy(argv_copy_char[i].get(), &argv_copy[i][0], argv_copy[i].size());
        argv_copy_char[i][argv_copy[i].size()] = '\0';
    }

    // what should i put here ?? --------------------vvv
    v8::V8::SetFlagsFromCommandLine(&argc, &(argv_copy_char[0].get()), true);
```

I tried both string and char [] based approach. It is giving compiler errors :

```
error C2102: '&' requires l-value
```

Using `&(argv_copy_char[0]._Myptr)` gives me Runtime errors at

`if (arg != NULL && *arg == '-') {` in `flags.cc`.

The signature of the function SetFlagsFromCommandLine is

`SetFlagsFromCommandLine (int *argc, char **argv, bool remove_flags)`.

What should i do ?

Comment: Can you not just pass the original `argv`? Do you need it unchanged later?

Comment: @ downvoter please explain the reason too. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have constructed and filled the vector of strings: `std::vector<std::string> argv_copy;` but
I don't understand why you have decided to use this vector to create another vector that will hold elements of type `unique_ptr<char[]>`:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<char[]> > argv_copy_char;
```

Also note that the prototype of `v8::V8::SetFlagsFromCommandLine` is:

```
static void SetFlagsFromCommandLine (int *argc, char **argv, bool remove_flags)
```

... exposing the vector's internals wouldn't be very lucky idea here, since `argv_copy` holds objects of type `std::string`... yet the API requires `char**`, so what you could do is dynamically allocate and fill a temporary C-style array of pointers to these strings:

```
// temporary C-style array
int myArgvSize = argv_copy.size();
char* myArgv[] = new char* [myArgvSize];
for (int i = 0; i < myArgvSize; ++i)
    myArgv[i] = &argv_copy[i][0];

v8::V8::SetFlagsFromCommandLine(&myArgvSize, myArgv, true);

// cleanup:
delete[] myArgv;
```

just note that this solution relies on the fact that `SetFlagsFromCommandLine` will not modify the length of these strings.

Comment: argc should also reflect the argv_copy.size()

Comment: Note that `SetFlagsFromCommandLine` almost certainly modifies its `argv` argument, so he has to update his `argv_copy` after calling it to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

why do `SetFlagsFromCommandLine` gets a pointer to integer? is it need to change the integer?i don't see why will you want to pass a pointer to it.

also the problem seems to be in a completely different place, so the code you shared isn't much helpful

finally, look at the line you got the error in. check:

1. what is `arg`? is it defined?
2. can `arg` be NULL?
3. is `arg` a pointer or an array?

Comment: The signature for that function is [`SetFlagsFromCommandLine (int *argc, char **argv, bool remove_flags)`](http://izs.me/v8-docs/classv8_1_1V8.html#a63157ad9284ffad1c0ab62b21aadd08c).

Comment: @DCoder, if it accepts `char **argv`, then just pass it the `argv`... `char **argv` and `char *argv[]` are different ways to write down the same thing.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall I have to first remove some flags. so need to make a copy.

Comment: Got it error was in passing argc in function it should be the new argument counter after removing some flags i.e. size of argc_copy_char

Comment: @ASHISHNEGI soo... did my answer helped you?

Comment: @ASHISHNEGI Why first?

Comment: @JamesKanze Because we have to use a library V8 that does not startup if you pass it some unknown arguments. From the command line we take arguments that may be ours or of lib we are using. This makes it easily customisable. We process ours then remove them them from it and send argv ahead for further processing.

Comment: @ASHISHNEGI That's horrible.  It means that you have to know _all_ of the arguments it it might expect, and remove any others.  I would consider the behavior you describe a serious bug.  (The example code in [http://izs.me/v8-docs/shell_8cc-example.html] calls `SetFlagsFromCommandLine`, and then processes the argument list.  This is the standard way of doing things.)

Comment: That is the same code i am using but the problem is not with SetFlagsFromCommandLine. The code following it for which removing these options is a must. That code actually executes the option thinking it as javascript. So since i must remove it  sooner or later, i just removed it in the starting to do as little changes as required.

Answer (score 1):

`SetFlagsFromCommandLine` looks like a fairly special function
to me, in that it seems to expect `argc` and `argv` as
arguments, and *modifies* them (presumably by removing options).
If at all possible, I would call it first, with `argc` and
`argv`, and do my special handling after.  The modification
probably takes place in the form of shifting pointers in `argv`
down, which means that any solution using `std::vector` will
require some additional handling after calling the function.

If you cannot change the order of handling (e.g. because
`--ipc-in-channel` and its argument might be extracted by
`SetFlagsFromCommandLine`), then you'll probably need something
like the following (after you've parsed your args):

```
std::vector<char*> tmp;
for ( auto current = argv_copy.begin();
        current != argv_copy.end();
        ++ current ) {
    tmp.push_back( current->empty ? "" : &(*current)[0] );
}
int argc_copy = tmp.size();
SetFlagsFromCommandLine( &argc_copy, &tmp[0] );
if ( argc_copy != argv_copy.size() ) {
    auto dest = argv_copy.begin();
    auto src = tmp.begin();
    while ( dest != argv_copy.end() ) {
        if ( (*src)[0] == '\0' ) {
            if ( *dest != "" ) {
                ++ dest ;
            } else {
                while ( dest != argv_copy.end() && *dest != "") {
                    dest = argv.erase( dest );
                }
            }
        } else {
            if ( !dest->empty() && &(*dest)[0] == *src ) {
                ++ dest;
            } else {
                while( dest != argv_copy.end() 
                        && (dest->empty() || &(*dest)[0] != *src) ) {
                    dest = argv.erase( dest );
                }
            }
        }
    }
    assert( argv_copy.size() == argc_copy );
}
```

This is just off the top of my head, and probably contains some
errors, but it gives an idea of the effort necessary *if* you
cannot call `SetFlagsFromCommandLine` first.

EDIT:

Alternatively, and although it is a bit of a pain, you can
process `argc` and `argv` in exactly the same way
`SetFlagsFromCommandLine` does internally, without putting them
in an `std::vector`:

```
int dest = 1;
int source = 1;
while ( source != argc ) {
    if ( inChannelParam == argv[source] == 0 && source < argc - 1 ) {
        inChannelName = argv[source + 1];
        source += 2;
    } else if ( outChannelPara == argv[source] == 0 && source < argc - 1 ) {
        outChannelName = argv[source + 1];
        source += 2;
    } else {
        argv[dest] = argv[source];
        ++ dest;
        ++ source;
    }
}
argc = dest;
SetFlagsFromCommandLine( &argc, argv );
std::vector<std::string> argv_copy( argv, argv + argc );
```

It's not fun dealing with `char**` et al., but since you need
this format later, it's probably less of a pain than translating
multiple times between the formats.

Comment: The v8 library using SetFlagsFromCommandLine does not start up if you pass it unknown arguments. so i process  mine first if they are present and send the rest to SetFlagsFromCommandLine.

Comment: @ASHISHNEGI The example code for using the v8 library calls `SetFlagsFromCommandLine` first, and then parses any additional arguments.  The specifications don't really say much about this, but I very much doubt that what you say is the case.  You've misunderstood the documentation of v8.

Comment: FWIW: I'd be willing to bet that internally, `SetFlagsFromCommandLine` does very much what I do in my second example above.  This is an almost universal way of handling options in C.  (Formally, it's not supported by the C standard, but it is universal, and I've never heard of an implementation where it didn't work.)